# in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: json, ruby, terraform

I found a script online to extract a JSON terraform state file and convert it to a HCL file. I get this error on the `attributes` definition line of the script:

```
in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I tried to find a solution online but I don't know Ruby.

Here is the script:

```
resource_key = ARGV.shift || usage
resource_type, resource_name = resource_key.split('.')
resource_id = ARGV.shift || usage

require 'justrun'
status = JustRun.command "terraform import #{resource_type}.#{resource_name} #{resource_id}" do |line, type|
  out = type == 'stdout' ? $stdout : $stderr
  out.puts line
end   

require 'json'
state = JSON.load File.read 'terraform.tfstate'

attributes = state['modules'][0]['resources'][resource_key]['primary']['attributes']

resource = {}

attributes.each do |attr, value|
  if attr.include? '.#'
    attr_array, _ = attr.split '.#'
    resource[attr_array] = []
    attributes.keys.select { |e| e.start_with? "#{attr_array}." }.each do |key|
      next if key == attr
      resource[attr_array] << attributes[key]
    end
  elsif attr.include? '.%'
    attr_array, _ = attr.split '.%'
    resource[attr_array] = {}
    attributes.keys.select { |e| e.start_with? "#{attr_array}." }.each do |key|
      next if key == attr
      new_key = key[attr_array.size + 1 .. -1]
      resource[attr_array][new_key] = attributes[key]
    end
  elsif attr.include? '.'
    next
  # elsif attr == 'id'
  #   next
  else
    resource[attr] = value
  end
end
```

Comment: As you see in the first line, it collects data from a previously defined `state` variable. But if you just copy-paste this script into an empty .rb file, the `state` variable would not be populated and therefore will be empty (also `resource_key` will be `nil` too). You have to initialize this variable with some data before using it. 

Please describe what do you want to achieve and the location from where you grabbed this script.

Comment: What is in `state`? Add `puts state` as the first line of the script and share the output

Comment: I added the state line in the code. 
State is a JSON terraform state file

Comment: what is in the file you're loading?

Comment: a JSON terraform state file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
state['modules']
```

If this is the first line of the script, Ruby doesn't know what the `state` variable is and raises an error when it tries get any values from this.

It looks like you expect it to be a hash, but it's empty... probably something is missing before this script.